# Hibernate OneToOne to an entity that has OneToMany

Tags: hibernate, lazy-loading, one-to-many, one-to-one

I have 2 entities.
Entity nr.1 contains a few fields and some collections, mapped one to many LAZY, and entity nr.2 has a OneToOne relationship to this one.

When i want to retrieve entity nr.2, all of the onetomany in entity nr. 1 are retrieved as well, even though they are LAZY.
I am not talking about a method, simply retrieving one entity nr.2 and entity nr.1 without its collections.

Thank you

Code examples:

This is entity nr. 2, which contains a OneToOne rel to entity nr.2 which is specified so:

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="id_employee")
public Employee getEmployee() {
    return employee;
}

public void setEmployee(Employee employee) {
    this.employee = employee;
}
```

And this is entity nr.1 which has many collections like so:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="employee", orphanRemoval = true)
@JsonManagedReference
@XmlElement
public Set<Phone> getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public void setPhone(Set<Phone> phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}
```

Ant Employee has many collections, including address and so on, which i do not want to be shown.
When i return entity nr. 2, it shows me Employee with all of its rels, and i do not need that. It also gives me the famous LazyInitexcepetion, although i do not explicitily request address or phone...

Comment: can you please share your code

Comment: I have shared it, thank you

Comment: when you said 'return nr.2' do you mean you do not want it shown/represented as xml or json? (i assume you are exposing it as a rest endpoint since you have xml and json annotations). if it is the case why not add XmlTransient and JsonIgnore annotations in your getEmployee?

Comment: I think JsonIgnore will simply not represent some mentioned field, but the query will still be executed, and that is my problem. I am trying to improve db performance, bandwith is not an issue at the moment, but it could be.

Answer (score 0):

```
@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="id_employee")
public Employee getEmployee() {
    return employee;
}
```

**From the JPA 2.0 spec, the defaults are like so:**

```
OneToMany: LAZY
ManyToOne: EAGER
ManyToMany: LAZY
OneToOne: EAGER
```

Comment: Nope, lazy init exception

Comment: And loading it explicitily gives me serialization error.

Comment: share the code giving lazy initialization exception.  If you are doing something like  object.employee().getSomething() it ll cause of lazy initialization , because it is loading lazily now.

Comment: What i meant is that i am not requesting explicitily as i said. This is a REST service that returns a json with entity nr.2, but which unfortunately contains the collections of the Employee object, and that is the problem.

Comment: I solved it in the meantime with custom selects and setters.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it in the meantime by using custom queries. So i get only what i need from the OneToOne entitites and then i use the main entity's setter to set those collections without fetching everyting. Major cut down on no of selects and bandwith.